# Proving Convergence of Partial Sums

Tags: analysis

Can someone help me prove that the series $\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ is convergent? I get that we can show that the partial sums converge, but when looking at how say $\frac{(-1)^i}{\sqrt{i}}+\frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{\sqrt{i+1}}+...+\frac{(-1)^j}{\sqrt{j}},$ is there a closed form that we use to show that this is less than say our error term $\frac{1}{n}?$ Thanks!

Comment: What did you try? You cannot get any answer before you say what you've tried.

Comment: @Nightflight I looked at simple cases like if took say i = 10, then i+1 = 11, and then at like 99 and 100 and I can see convergence, but in proving generally, I just don't know of a quick general way to formulate the sum and how that is smaller than some error term - like I just don't know what the series summation formula/"trick" is

Comment: Try to simplify one pair of terms and see what you get.